# xcode project manager closes folders when running app

Tags: xcode

Every time I run my app in Xcode on the iOS Simulator, the folders in the project navigation pane all reset to just showing the closed top-level folders.

I then have to re-drill-down to the code, opening all the folders on the way; but then when I run the app again we're back to square one.

There's presumably a really obvious settings button somewhere that I'm missing and have hit by accident, as I don't recall it doing this in the past. Can anyone point me towards it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was introduced when using Apple's avgtool to increment a build number with each commit. For some reason this re-set the folders in the navigation pane. Removing avgtool solved the problem.

Comment: It's back; with a different cause.   Suddenly happening in Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is a problem with full screen mode; the run button triggers the close button.   Make a window, make it large, and then you don't have the problem.   See [apple stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151447/xcode-6-on-yosemite-crashing-in-fullscreen-mode-when-build-running-app-on-devi) for more information.